# Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll' while trying to install tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow.

I have installed Cuda10.0 and cudnn, but I still get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
        ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
      File "D:\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] 找不到指定的模块。
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/Python_test/Python算法成品/机器学习/test/test.py", line 4, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
      File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
        self_check.preload_check()
      File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
        % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
    ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: `enter code here`https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

***To fix the issue, either:*** Install CUDA from September 2018, which comes with `cudart64_100.dll` and other `32 bit *100.dlls` and `64 bit *100 libraries`.

***Or, if you want future support:***

- Install the latest `NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit`.
- However, because the newest version of the CUDA library is `cudart64_101.dll` and TensorFlow 2.0 requires the older `cudart64_100.dll`, also install the CUDA from September 2018.
- Then copy `cudart64_100.dll` library from the old install of CUDA to the new one.
- Or just download the library from the file attached further below and copy it into your last CUDA installation directory in program files.

For more details please refer [here](https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/)